# Rails: Friendly_id gem friendly url not working for 1 model, but working for other(s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

**Issue**: I have installed the friendly_id gem, it is working how it supposed to for my Users table, but for my Listings model, the friendly URL to use a :name instead of :id isn't working.

**Here's my Listings controller in a nutshell**:

```
    def show
        @order = @listing.orders.new()
#as you can see, I have no need for a find because i noticed i didn't need it for the show page to show up correctly - idk
    end

    private

    def set_listing
          @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end
```

What's confusing to me is that I don't even need something like `@listing=Listing.find(params[:id]`

**I tried using this in the show**: `@listing=Listing.friendly.find(params[:id]`

but it didn't make a difference.  I also tried changing the "set_listing" method to include the friendly snippet but that didn't help either - just a shot even though it shouldn't work.

**I included this in the model - just like i did for my Users table**:

```
extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

For example, I have my listing, id: 1, name: Listing Test 1, slug: listing-test-1

I go to domain.com/listings/listing-test-1 and I get

Couldn't find Listing with 'id'=listing-test-1

I did everything the same as I did with the Users table but it doesn't seem to work.

**Question**: Is there something can be interfering with this issue?

Comment: Why is the def set_listing method private?

Comment: For 1, it's just standard for rails and how a scaffold creates it.  and 2 you just made me look it up and it seems because set_entercontrollernamehere will only ever interact with the said controller itself and no need to be public

Comment: Are you sure, that slug was generated for Listing with id: 1? Did you check it in the console? Try to stop rails server and run `spring stop && rails server`

Comment: @Crashtor every method in your controller which is not an action that corresponds to a route (such as callback methods) should be declared private.

Answer (score 0):

FriendlyId does not override the default [`.find`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) method on your model. Well at least not since version 5 was released way back in 2013.

To lookup a record based on the id and slug column you need to explicitly call `.friendly.find`:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # ...

  def show
    @order = @listing.orders.new()
  end

  # ...

  private

  def set_listing
    @listing = Listing.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  # ...
end
```

The reason you are currently getting an error is most likely that `before_action :set_listing` calls the `set_listing` method before the show action is called.

```
class ListingsController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    # this line is never reached - and should not really be needed anyways
    @listing = Listing.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @order = @listing.orders.new()
  end

  private

  def set_listing
    # will raise ActiveRecord::NotFoundError
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Since `Listing.find(params[:id])` will raise an `ActiveRecord::NotFoundError` you never reach the show action. The solution is just to fix the callback method in the first place.

Comment: I know it's been a while but I have revisited this and this still won't work.  Please explain what you mean because what you have above is everything i tried from stated in my OP.  I tried adding friendly to both the set_listing and to the show, vice versa, with and without. I think the issue because of the `@order = @listing.orders.new()` situation and not even calling the @listing in the show.

Comment: “It does not work” is not helpful. What is the exact error message?

Comment: There is no error messages.  Nothing gets inputted into the friendly_id schema, the route using the slug doesn't work.

Comment: @uno are you sure you created a migration for the listing model?
`rails g migration AddSlugToListings slug:uniq` It will be helpful to see the exact error log too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same challenge when working on a **Rails 6** application.

**Here's how I solved it**:

By default [Friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem does not generate slugs for existing records in a Rails application. So if you have existing records for a model, slugs won't be generated for them. They will only be generated for newer records.

To generate slugs for existing records, do the following. Say our model name is `Listing` and the column we want to use for the slug is `name`, just do the following:

Start your rails console using:

```
rails console
```

and run the command below to generate slugs for existing records:

```
  Listing.find_each(&:save)
```

Restart your rails server, and check again. You should see slugs now for all the records.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**